# Deleting columns depending on position of characters in a string

Tags: string, vba, excel

I'm still new to VBA and couldn't find any solution using the search-function so far.
Problem:
I have (in this case ten sheets) a row with over 500 cells containing strings with 5-7 words.
Now I need to delete all columns where the searched word is not the last word,but the word is in all cells (in the row) at different positions in the string.
I tried this:

```
Dim examinee As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim word As String
Dim myCell As String

examinee = InputBox("How many sheets?")
word = InputBox("Looking for?")

For A = 1 To examinee

Sheets("sheet" & A).Select
On Error Resume Next
Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlToRight)).Select
    For Each Cell In Selection.Cells
        myCell = Right(Cell, Len(Cell) - (InStrRev(Cell, " ") - 1))
        MsgBox myCell ' just to be sure the word is found
        If myCell Like word Then
        Selection.Cells.Bold = False
        Else
        Delete.Column
        End If
    Next Cell
Next
```

I can find&identify the word and "If" works fine so far, just nothing happens to the selected cell and the column wasn't deleted.
With some changes I can only delete the entire row but it isn't what I need.
Any help appriciated.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but I'd recommend cleaning up the syntax. I've removed the code where you're selecting ranges (there's lots of info online about why you shouldn't do this).

An array is created to find the last word and that's tested against the search value.

```
Sub Test()
Dim examinee As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim word As String
Dim myCell As String
Dim arr() As String
Dim strLastWord As String

'How Many Sheets Should We Loop?
examinee = InputBox("How many sheets?")
'What Word Are We Searching For?
word = InputBox("Looking for?")
'Loop Sheets
For A = 1 To examinee
    'Loop Cells In Row 3
    For Each cell In Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlToRight))
        'Get The Value Of The Current Cell
        myCell = Right(cell, Len(cell) - (InStrRev(cell, " ") - 1))
        'Is It A Single Word?
        If InStr(1, myCell, " ") Then
            'Several Words. Create An Array Of Individual Words In The Cell
            arr() = Split(myCell, " ")
            'Get The Number Of The Last Word
            strLastWord = arr(UBound(arr))
        Else
            'Single Word. Get The Word
            strLastWord = myCell
        End If
        'Is The Last Word = The Search Word?
        If strLastWord = word Then
            'Yes. Make It Bold
            cell.Font.Bold = True
        Else
            'No. Delete The Column
            Columns(cell.Column).Delete
        End If
    Next cell
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
Sub findtext()

Dim wsAkt As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim strWord As String
Dim intWord As Integer

'get the word
strWord = Application.InputBox("Looking for?")
'length of word
intWord = Len(strWord)
'loop through all worksheets
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    'variable for selected worksheet
     Set wsAkt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
    'get how many columns are in row 3
    x = wsAkt.Cells(3, wsAkt.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'loop through row 3 columns
        For k = 1 To x
            'if last Word in cell = the word then it has to have the same length
            If Right(wsAkt.Cells(3, k), intWord) <> strWord Then
                'delete selected column
                wsAkt.Columns(k).Delete
            End If
        Next k
 Next i

 End Sub
```

(Its not tested)

Comment: Thank you, I have to take a closer look to it und try to understand the code, right now every cell with the word is found, but I need only those where the word is the last in the sentence. Hope I can figure it out myself.